# Write repeated Strings to BigQuery using Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a data stream containing `Strings` which look like `JSONArrays`. I want to parse those Strings and write to BigQuery table using Apache Beam but am getting an error while writing repeated Strings.

Here´s how I convert my string to `TableRow`:

```
    String dataString = "[{\"EMAIL\": [\"zog@yahoo.com\"]}]";

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(dataString);
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONArray emailArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("EMAIL").toString());

      tableRow.set("EMAIL", emailArray); //Results in error
    }
```

Here´s what my BigQuery schema looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "EMAIL",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "REPEATED"
  }
]
```

I have managed to write a similar repeated String to BigQuery table using Python but unable to do it using Apache Beam. I suppose I am not saving the right key-value pair in `TableRow`. The error I am getting now is:

```
java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"email","message":"This field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
```

I need help regarding how to save a similar repeated String to BigQuery without creating a record and would appreciate any advice or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error message seems likely to be because of attempting to set EMAIL to an incorrect value. Is the dataString example you have accurate? Because if I'm interpreting it correctly, it's an array with two `JSONObjects`, the first with only the `EMAIL` field defined, and the second with only the `ValidFrom` field defined. I could see problems coming up if the `EMAIL` field is getting set to NULL when writing to BQ.

Comment: The data string is accurate, yes, Daniel. But pardon my mistake in not checking the type of element anywhere. Since I am checking the data types in my original code, I removed the unnecessary code in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to create

1. one row with a **concatenated String** of email addresses, or
2. a **row per email**, or
3. one row with a repeated field.

Note that is seems your `ValidFrom` field is of type `STRING`, *not* a repeated field, unless it is wrapped in a repeated field in a hierarchical schema.

In the example code you provided, you are creating a `JSONArray` and putting it into the `STRING` field, which I think cause issues as the types are incompatible. If you want to keep it as a plain `STRING` field, you can use Solution 1 below.

Also make sure that the name of your column in BigQuery matches the one in your code, I see you use both `ValidFrom` and `EMAIL` (might be a mistake in your posted code though).

### Solution 1: One row with String field

In case you want to add **one row** with a **concatenated** `String` field in BigQuery, you can use the following:

```java
// Initialize your final row
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();

// Find email addresses
String [] emails = ... // your extraction logic

// Build a concatenated string of emails
String allEmails = String.join(";", emails);

// Add the string field to the row
tableRow.set('EMAILS', allEmails);
```

### Solution 2: Multiple rows with String field

In case you want to insert **multiple rows**, you your create multiple table rows:

```java
// Find email addresses
String [] emails = ... // your extraction logic

// Build a row per email
for(String email: emails) {
    // Initialize your final row
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
    tableRow.set('EMAIL', email);
    
    // TODO: do something with the row (add to list, or ...)
}
```

### Solution 3: One row with REPEATED field

In case you want to add **one row** with a `REPEATED STRING` field in BigQuery, you can use the following:

```java
// Initialize your final row
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();

// Find email addresses
String [] emails = ... // your extraction logic

// Build the repeated field
List<String> emailCells = new ArrayList<>();
for(String email: emails) {
    emailCells.add(email);
}

// Add the repeated field to the row
tableRow.set('EMAILS', emailCells);
```

If this is not what you're aiming for, please provide some more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jonny5, for the detailed answer. I used Solution 3 and successfully managed to write the repeated Strings to BigQuery. Appreciate your help.